# HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions

Tags: hibernate, session, orm, sql-delete

Here is my tables:

`Orders.java`

```
@Entity
public class Orders implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;
@Column(nullable = false)
private Date orderDate;
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private User user;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "orders", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<OrderItem> orderItems = new HashSet<OrderItem>();
//getter/setters
```

I am going to delete one record from `Orders` table:

`OrderServiceImple.java`:

```
@Transactional
public void deleteOrder(String oid) {
    Orders ordersToDelete = orderDao.findById(oid);
    System.out.println("orders To Delete: " + ordersToDelete); // retrieved correctly
    orderDao.delete(ordersToDelete); // exception is here
}
```

This is `delete()` in `oderDaoImpl`:

`OrderDaoImpl.java`:

```
@Component
public class OrderDaoImpl implements OrderDao<Orders, Integer>, Serializable {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private Session session;

public Session getSession() {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    return session;
 }

public void delete(Orders entity) {
    getSession().delete(entity);
  }
}
```

I tried `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(entity)` in `delete()` but get the same error.

Exception:

```
04-May-2015 15:49:18.929 WARNING [http-apr-8080-exec-2] null.null #{myCardBean.deleteOrder()}: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions
 javax.faces.FacesException: #{myCardBean.deleteOrder()}: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions
    at 

com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions
    at 
org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.setCurrentSession(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:633)
```

**UPDATE:**

```
public Orders findById(String id) {
    Orders foundOrders = (Orders) getSession().get(Orders.class, Integer.parseInt(id)); // should be Integer
    return foundOrders;
}
```

Comment: Do you have some weird implementation in the entity class?

Comment: @StefanSteinegger Sorry, what's your mean?

Comment: I mean some special code in the getter or setter of a collection in the `Orders` entity or one of its children.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger I put the `Ordes` entity.

Comment: Can you please provide the type of error?

Comment: @Brain I put the exception, see updated `exception` code.

Comment: I wonder if this is all executed in the same transaction. (I saw the @transaction annotation. I don't know this well enough to say if this is all you have to do and how to break it). If findById and delete are both creating their own transaction, this kind of error probably may happen.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger I put the `findById()` see `UPDATE`. I need to first find order , and then delete that order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in `currentsession()` of `SessionFactory` in both methods.

In `findById(String id)` and in `delete(Orders entity)`